# Providing an abstract class which extends a Guice AbstractModule and has provides methods

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I want to provide a Guice AbstractModule which has a few providers annotated with protected annotations so that those values can only be used by the extending class.

```
public abstract class AssetModule extends AbstractModule {

  /** Protected annotation to inject the underlying {@link Asset} payload. */
  @Qualifier
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  protected @interface ProtectedAssetPayload {}

  @Qualifier
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  public @interface ParentPublicAnnotation {}

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    install(new Framework());
  }

  private final class Framework extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {}

    @Provides
    @ParentPublicAnnotation
    String getPublicValue() {
      return "public value";
    }

    @Provides
    @ProtectedAssetPayload
    protected String getAssetPayload() {
      return "payload";
    }
  }
}
```

Which would allow me to extend the asset so:

```
public final class SomeAssetModule extends AssetModule {
  @Qualifier
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  public @interface ChildPublicAnnotation {}

  @Provides
  @ChildPublicAnnotation
  String concactToPayload(@ProtectedAssetPayload String payload) {
    return String.format("concact_%s", payload);
  }
}
```

And use both of the publicly annotated bindings in a third class:

```
public final class Foo {
  private final String a;
  private final String b;

  @Inject
  public Foo(@ParentPublicAnnotation String a, @ChildPublicAnnotation String b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }
}
```

When I try to run this I get an errors which look like:

```
No implementation for java.lang.String annotated with @ParentPublicAnnotation() was bound

No implementation for java.lang.String annotated with @ProtectedAssetPayload() was bound
```

It seems that Guice only binds the provider methods in the implementing SomeAssetModule class, and ignores the bindings in the super class.
Any thoughts on how to force Guice to actually bind the provides methods in the super class?

Cheers!

Comment: You have used `SomePublicAnnotation` in `AssetModule` where you meant to use `ParentPublicAnnotation`. With the error corrected the setup you have is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, was a typo when I wrote the question to simplify the problem.  Same error is still present.

Comment: The code runs fine for me under Java 8 with Guice 4.0. I copied and pasted your code exactly. The fix to the annotation is the only change I made. How are you creating and using the injector? My test method contains this code: `Guice.createInjector(new SomeAssetModule()).getInstance(Foo.class);`

Comment: Hmm... when I simplified the problem I changed it from a specialized ThrowingProvider to @Provides.  Seems like the issue might be with ThrowingProviders.

Comment: Yep, that's it. You can't inject the class provided by a ThrowingProvider directly. You can only inject the provider. Because the `get()` method of a ThrowingProvider can throw an exception, you always have to call it explicitly.